# How do I convert my apache 2.0 module project to C++?

Tags: c++, apache2

I already developed a C based module for my Apache 2.0 environment and it works well but I am not a total expert at C programming so I would like benefits of C++ try/catch, strings, and other C++ benefits.

While researching Apache modules, I ran across several articles that said specifically all work needed to be in C and not C++; however, I just download the Apache openid module "mod_auth_openid" and it is programmed in C++. I noticed the use of the extern keyword, while reading the code.

Can anyone confirm that I can use C++, and how I would go about it? I am not sure if I may post the code here because of the licensing.

Please let me know what other information I may provide and thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some open source framework propose C++ layer to apache2.0 module environment such as [WSO2CPP](http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/cpp/). Code provided is not so complex to understand if you don't want to introduce such a library between your code and apache.

You may be interested in the `ServiceSkeleton` class ...